# Displaying QGIS attribute table on the right

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, gui, dockable-window

Is it possible to dock QGIS attribute table on the right?

I know it is possible to display it on top and bottom, but for my project it would be better to dock it on right (or left) side.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 15):

Agree with @JochenSchwarze that it makes sense to have it (and thanks for making it a *feature request*).

Saying that, **it is possible** to do it with a bit of Python.

---

1. Make sure the **Open attribute table in a dock window** setting is enabled from the menubar:

   ```
   Settings > Options > Data Sources > Feature attributes and table > Open attribute...
   ```
2. Restart QGIS and then open **both** the Python Console (`Plugins > Python Console` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and the Attribute Table of your **selected** layer.
3. Then type the following into the Python Console:

   ```
   from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
   from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

   attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable']
   iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, attrTables[0])
   ```

---

Your attribute table should now be docked to the right:

[image: Attribute table]

---

And if you want to dock it to the left, replace

```
iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, attrTables[0])
```

with

```
iface.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, attrTables[0])
```

Comment: Can we agree on that it IS impossible to a 'normal' user expecting it to work via drag and drop and for shure it IS possible if one knows about python, wich in most cases cannot be taken for granted (Saying this is, I daresay, like saying "It is possible to order a meal in Shanghai with a bit of chinese") ;-)

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Haha! Yes completely agree that this is not a 'normal method' at all! Would be a nice feature to implement as drag-and-drop ;)

Answer (score 7):

Seems impossible at the moment. But I strongly agree that it makes sense. I have just started a feature request in the QGIS issue tracker https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14941

Comment: Was just fixed: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/df6d2c631c171e962d9199614a0815b35fe418bd hope this answers the question? ;-)

Comment: I believe it does! In which case, your answer should be accepted =)

Comment: If I have Qgis installed, I have to reinstall?