# Change symbols outline color without losing fill pattern

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, outline, fill

I have defined a layer symbology like shown in the screenshot below (categories are applicable laws however).

[image]

The layer symbology is defined like this i.e. (no pattern fill):

[image]

For these three categories it would be no big deal to change the outline color separately, but imagine some tens of categories this would be linear time consuming.

So is there a way to change some aspect of the symbology (like the outline color) ***at once*** without losing the settings for the fill style?

Comment: Do you want the same border color as the line fills?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select your symbols by either clicking them individually whilst holding **Ctrl** or click the uppermost symbol, hold **Shift** and click the last symbol you want selected. Then go to `Symbol > Change`:

[image: Categorised style]

Then select your fill and set the border style:

[image: Symbol Properties]

When you click `OK`, the selected symbols should be updated with the new border properties:

[image: Style resuls]

---

**EDIT**:

To keep your pattern fills, a possible workaround is after you have **categorised** your layer, change it to **Rule-based**. This will create expressions for each of your symbol which should match the categorised version. Then create a new rule which has a transparent fill and set your border with the required settings and with **no filter/rule**:

[image: Border]

You should now have features which contain your pattern fill but with the border you have set:

[image: Result]

Comment: Yes and no. The categories each keep their fill colors, but the fill style is made all the same. Check this out if you assign different fill styles (Solid, BDiagonal, Horizontal,...) to some few of your categories and do again what you have done. I tried this with 2.14.3 and 2.8.9 LTR.

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Edited the post with a possible workaround. Don't think this is possible manually (yet) but could probably be done using Python.

Comment: This is what I learned from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195827/displaying-qgis-attribute-table-on-the-right, everything is possible with a bit of python ;-)

Comment: But besides, nice workaround. If I make it using bit of python I'll post it here.

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Haha! Yes, glad you looked at a possible python solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of python that does the trick. That layer-renderer-symbol-symbollayer thing is a bit weird at first sight, but ok.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor

r = iface.activeLayer().rendererV2()
for s in r.symbols():
    s.symbolLayers()[0].setOutlineColor(QColor('#ffff00'))
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Just tested this on the console and it works for the first time, but trying it a second time leeds to

[image]

Comment: interesting! Your code works fine on Ubuntu, Qgis 2.14.3 (although the last line should be `iface.mapCanvas().refresh()` ..?). At least it does when written into a .py file (rather than being pasted direct into the console).

Comment: Added parantheses, Test it with 2.14.3 on Windows later.