# Docking Attribute Table using PyQgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, dockable-window

Is it possible to dock the attribute table using pyqgis? For instance, docking it to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: If using QGIS 2.x, then this post might be helpful: [Displaying QGIS attribute table on the right](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195827/displaying-qgis-attribute-table-on-the-right). Simply replace `Qt.RightDockWidgetArea` with `Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea` :)

Comment: @Joseph Thanks, do you know if it is possible to change the settings of QGIS through pyqgis as well? I would like it to work for more than just me.

Comment: was the question "docking the attribute table **to the bottom of the screen**" _regardless of QGIS window's position_ ? :-p

Comment: @snaileater I ment the bottom of QGIS window :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is the setting `Open attribute table in a dock window` which automatically opens the attribute table in the *bottom dock window*. You can set this manually via the menubar:

```
Settings > Options > Data Sources > Open attribute table in a dock window
```

---

Or via PyQGIS:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/dockAttributeTable", True)
```

Comment: @KasperSkjeggestad - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

To do this in Qgis 3.x (expanding on the [accepted answer by @Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/281721/106634)), use:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/dockAttributeTable", True)

# And to check the current value of the setting
QSettings().value("/Qgis/dockAttributeTable")
```