# Docking Symbology / Layer Properties window in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dockable-window

In QGIS, is there a way to make the "Layer Properties" (aka the "Vector Properties" window) docked to the right side of the screen?

More specifically, the "Symbology" tab.

I ask this because sometimes I just want to more easily change the reference attribute the map is being colored by, and having to double click on the layer to open the "Layer Properties" window and choosing the correct tab adds a few pesky clicks I would like to avoid.

I found an answer at [Displaying QGIS attribute table on the right](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195827) for another window, but I'm having a hard time adapting the answer to this case.

I'm currently using QGIS 3.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `view` menu, then `panels` and check the box beside `layer styling`