# How to add DockWidget above the Layer panel using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, pyqt, qt

I'm trying to dock an attribute table on the left hand side of my window, **above** the Layers panel.

By enabling `"Open new attribute tables as docked windows"` (under `Settings Options > Data Sources > Feature attributes and table` and using code I adopted from [Displaying QGIS attribute table on the right](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/195832/106634), I can do something like:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication

# Display the attribute table (by default it appears at the bottom)
iface.showAttributeTable(some_layer)

# Find, and move attribute table to left hand dock widget area 
attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable']
iface.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, attrTables[0])
```

However, the attribute table appears underneath the layers panel.  How do I get it to appear above it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *re-add* the Layers Panel which would place it **below any existing panels**:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget

iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())

# Get active Attribute Table
attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable']
# Get Layers Panel
layersPanel = [x for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget) if x.objectName() == 'Layers']

# Add Attribute Table
iface.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, attrTables[0])
# Add (re-add) Layers Panel so that new panel appears below
iface.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, layersPanel[0])
```

---

[image: Attribute table above Layers Panel]